# Merging image-upload and image-uploading

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

[image-upload](/questions/tagged/image-upload) and [image-uploading](/questions/tagged/image-uploading) should be merged as both serves the same purpose, with `tag:image-uploading` retaining its position as the main tag as it defines the process itself, the tag's name being good grammatically and as per [Ozair Kafray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150789/ozair-kafray) pointed out, `image-uploading` has more questions tagged right now.

Comment: Also: the [tag:image-uploading] has 338 questions while [tag:image-upload] has around 80 questions.